# Custom splash screen for Eclipse plugin (Non-RCP)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to brand a plugin I developed for Eclipse. I am starting with a custom splash screen. What I want is to display a custom image when Eclipse starts-up, once my plugin is installed. Note that my plugin in **non-rcp**.

All the methods that I've found till now (Adding the **org.eclipse.ui.splashHandlers** extensions, and implementing a class that extends **EclipseSplashHandler**), I tried them already, but to no avail. No custom splash-screen shows-up on startup. I guess that these methods are specific to only Eclipse RCP applications.

Is there any way I can have my own custom image displayed when Eclipse starts-up? This will be only when the user installs my plugin.

Comment: Do you contribute/use UI elements to the IDE?

Comment: @efekctive I did not get you? Do you mean if I selected the check-box "This something something will make contributions to the UI" while starting with the project?

Comment: How does the user interact with your plugin?

Comment: There are just a couple of commands that the use fires using the mouse. Anyway, Greg's answer to this question says that doing this is not possible. I guess I'll just add an image to the "about" section of the plug-in.

Comment: I misread the question. I thought you wanted to do something else (branding of your plug-in) So yes, he is right to change the splash screen like sts, you would need a lot more than a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splash image location is specified in the RCP config.ini file, you can't really change the contents of that from  plugin. So this isn't possible. In any case a plugin should not be trying to change a product's splash screen.

You can add to the images in the About dialog using feature based branding.

Comment: You know, sir, this is the answer I was looking for. I was skeptical of this thing from the very beginning. Now that I know that it is not possible, I can stop trying.

Answer (score 1):

When by chance I saw the question I had a gut feeling this is feasable.

To deal with splash, one has to use Eclipse P2 (Povisioning platform) – this is the only way to achieve that. The second point is to substitute splash after the first Eclipse restart – for that [P2 touchpoint](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_actions_touchpoints.html&cp=2_0_20_1_3) is the only solution. In Eclipse splash can be set in two places:

1. in configuraiton/config.ini file, as osgi.splashPath
2. in eclipse.ini file, as -showsplash parameter

There were 2 tasks - to create that "touchpoint" and to install it before our feature itself is installed. I created a simple plug-in, proof of concept, that implements this functionality - it substitutes original Eclipse splash after installation and changes splash to photos of the day from Bing.com - meet [Bing splash plug-in](https://che4.github.io/bingsplash)!

Update site for Eclipse IDE - https://che4.github.io/

Comment: Good for a proof of concept. For actual production use, a minimalist variant without Bing and custom menu elements would have been nice. Basically something that has some written instructions that tell you to manually add a splash.bmp to the plugin's folder and change a path in the config.ini and have it work out of the box.

Comment: @crusha-k-rool, you should look at [touchpoint](https://github.com/che4/bing-splash/blob/develop/bing-splash.touchpoint/src/io/github/che4/touchpoint/BingSplashAction.java) - this is a place where we change Eclipse configuration to use our [splash](https://github.com/che4/bing-splash/blob/develop/bing-splash.feature/splash.bmp)