# Change eclipse splash screen

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, splash-screen, eclipse-luna

I'm working on a set of plugins for Eclipse Luna and I would like to customize eclipse splash screen(replace the one on the picture with a custom one).

[image: Default splash screen]

I wan't to set custom splash screen when users install my plugins. So far I only found a way by manually changing it in eclipse configurations. Is it possible to do this programatically from a plugin?

Comment: It seems unlikely that a plug-in to an existing product could override the product's splash screen. I think the splash screen is presented before and during the loading of plug-ins. And there could be multiple such plug-ins, all wanting to replace the splash. As you note, you can override it in configuration. For that, see also [How to set SplashScreen in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533403/)

Comment: No, a plugin can't change the splash screen. You have to build a new RCP with a new branding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace the splash.bmp under

```
{eclipse.dir}/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0.v20130605-2000/
```

Here the eclipse version is : 4.3.0.v20130605-2000
It may be different for you.

Comment: Thanks, I already found this way. I was looking for a bit more programmatic solution like to change it with some Java code in my plugin, so when someone installs my plugin the splash screen changes.

Comment: @IvanKulezic - look at [How to change Eclipse splash with my plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234135/custom-splash-screen-for-eclipse-plugin-non-rcp/50161000#50161000)